# ASP .net identity connection to custom sql database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to connect my asp .net identity classes to custom sql database. I have defined the mapping in the OnModelBuilder method as follows:

```
var user = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasKey(u => u.Id).ToTable("User");
            user.Property(iu => iu.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            user.Property(iu => iu.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
            user.Property(iu => iu.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("PasswordHash");
            user.Property(iu => iu.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("SecurityStamp");
            user.Property(iu => iu.EmailConfirmed).HasColumnName("EmailConfirmed");
            user.Property(iu => iu.LockoutEnabled).HasColumnName("LockoutEnabled");
            user.Property(iu => iu.LockoutEndDateUtc).HasColumnName("LockoutEndDateUtc");
            user.Property(iu => iu.PhoneNumber).HasColumnName("PhoneNumber");
            user.Property(iu => iu.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasColumnName("PhoneNumberConfirmed");
            user.Property(iu => iu.TwoFactorEnabled).HasColumnName("TwoFactorEnabled");
            user.Property(au => au.AccessFailedCount).HasColumnName("AccessFailedCount");
            user.Property(au => au.TwoFactorEnabled).HasColumnName("TwoFactorEnabled");


            //--?--
            user.HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
            user.HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
            user.HasMany(u => u.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
            user.Property(u => u.UserName).IsRequired();
            //--



            var applicationUser = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(au => au.Id).ToTable("User");

            applicationUser.Property(au => au.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("PasswordHash");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("SecurityStamp");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.EmailConfirmed).HasColumnName("EmailConfirmed");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.ActivationToken).HasColumnName("ActivationToken");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.LockoutEnabled).HasColumnName("LockoutEnabled");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.LockoutEndDateUtc).HasColumnName("LockoutEndDateUtc");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.PhoneNumber).HasColumnName("PhoneNumber");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasColumnName("PhoneNumberConfirmed");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.AccessFailedCount).HasColumnName("AccessFailedCount");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.Discriminator1).HasColumnName("Discriminator1");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.TwoFactorEnabled).HasColumnName("TwoFactorEnabled");
            applicationUser.Property(au => au.IdentityRole_Id).HasColumnName("IdentityRole_Id");

            //set the primary key for this class. Use .HasMaxLength(40) to specify max length on property
            var role = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey(ir => ir.Id).ToTable("Role");
            role.Property(ir => ir.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            role.Property(ir => ir.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

            var applicationRole = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasKey(ar => ar.Id).ToTable("Role");
            applicationRole.Property(ir => ir.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            applicationRole.Property(ir => ir.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
            //applicationRole.Property(ir => ir.Description).HasColumnName("Description");

            var userRole = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(iur => new{iur.UserId, iur.RoleId}).ToTable("UserRole");
            userRole.Property(ur => ur.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");
            userRole.Property(ur => ur.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");

            var claim = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().HasKey(iuc => iuc.Id).ToTable("UserClaim");
            claim.Property(iuc => iuc.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            claim.Property(iuc => iuc.ClaimType).HasColumnName("ClaimType");
            claim.Property(iuc => iuc.ClaimValue).HasColumnName("ClaimValue");
            claim.Property(iuc => iuc.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");

            var login = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(iul => new { iul.UserId, iul.LoginProvider, iul.ProviderKey }).ToTable("UserLogin");
            login.Property(iul => iul.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
            login.Property(iul => iul.LoginProvider).HasColumnName("LoginProvider");
            login.Property(iul => iul.ProviderKey).HasColumnName("ProviderKey");
```

However when I run, its giving error saying

```
Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
Invalid column name 'IdentityRole_Id'.
Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
```

If I understand correctly, its looking for those column names inside my custom User table, even though they are not defined in IdentityUser or my derived ApplicationUser.

I'm not sure where the error lies, my OnModelCreating method?

Comment: I tried [NotMappedAttribute] but that didn't work. That ignores my whole ApplicationUser class.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an ASP.NET identity issue. You are mapping both, base class and derived class,IdentityUser and ApplicationUser respectively to the same table "User", this is known as "table per class hierarchy", so EF adds Descriminator column accordingly. 
In this case you should mapp only ApplicationUser class.
The same applies to IdentityRole and ApplicationRole, etc.